# beforeSession in playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

I want to delete certain folder and file (allure-results folder)in the test directory before starting the test in playwright. WebdriverIO provide the options like beforeSession , i want to know is there any similar option available in playwright or how we can execute some code before starting the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution for this ,in playwright keep the code under  globalSetup function and that will be executed first

Answer (score 1):

I think beforeAll can solve your problem, you can see more at the [official docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-before-all).

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test.beforeAll(async () => {
  console.log('Before tests');
});

test.afterAll(async () => {
  console.log('After tests');
});

test('my test', async ({ page }) => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on when you actually want your code to run.

If it’s once before the entire testing run, you can make use of [the global setup option](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#global-setup-and-teardown). Or [use a dependency project](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-dependencies) (new in version 1.31).

Or if you want to run once before an entire set of tests within a file or once before each test in a set, you can use [the beforeAll or beforeEach hooks](https://playwright.dev/docs/writing-tests#using-test-hooks) respectively.

Or depending on your use case, there’s also the option of [creating custom fixtures](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#creating-a-fixture).